# Why is TFS ignoring a project in my solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I have multiple projects in our solution that is in our TFS 2010 repository. I've added about 5 new projects to this solution in recent days.

I have found that for one of the projects, that the project file itself will not check-in to TFS. All of the artifacts contained in this project are working fine; they are checked in and I can see them in the Team Explorer. But I cannot see the project file in Team Explorer, nor is their an icon next to the project in Solution Explorer that would indicate its checked in status.

Also, clicking on any of the TFS related option in the context menu in Visual Studio results in those options being applied to the file contained in the project, not the actual project itself.

Can this be remedied or do I have to create an entirely new project and add all of the artifacts from the old project back into it?

Comment: Does the project appear in the Source Control Explorer window?

Comment: @Toomai Yes it does, other than not being able to check it into TFS it behaves as just as you would expect.

Comment: If @Nick's comment about trying to add the file manually doesn't work then this is just a guess but check the id for the project in the solution and project files and make sure it isn't the same as another project in the same solution. If that isn't it, how did you create the project and what kind of project is it?

Comment: this program is absolutely unbelievable..

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Your project doesn't have appropriate Source Control Bindings!  With the solution open, you'll need to go to `File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control` to view the bindings for your projects.  The failing one probably will show an "Unknown" or not binded status.  You can then use that dialog to correct the binding and check in the project file.

Appended Alternate Solution -
Navigate to the `Team Explorer -> Source Control` and manually add the files using the "**Add Items to Folder**" menu item.

Comment: Hey Nick thanks for the response. I've checked as well, and it shows that project is bound, connected and valid. I've even tried unbinding it and then re-binding it back to see if it would force a check-in of that project. It did not. The project file is def. not in TFS, b/c a colleague noticed this problem when he could not download the project.

Comment: @aceinthehole - Sorry about that!  My mistake.  What happens if you go to the Source Control explorer and try to add the files manually rather than trying to do it via the Solution Explorer?

Comment: no worries! Thanks for you help. I ended up manually adding the project file via the Team Explorer, and it seems to have to have worked. I am not sure what caused it to begin with but it seems that others can now download the project as expect. If you would like, if you append your answer with the info from your last comment, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @aceinthehole - happy to help.  Answer appended.

Comment: @TheLegendaryCopyCoder This worked for me as well. I'm still not sure how it happened in the first place, though.

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters I never had this as well, only since I downloaded VS2017 it seems like TFS doesn't automatically track new projects. Luckily enough the first suggestion did the trick for me...

Comment: For VS 2019, the `Change Source Control` option is under `File -> Source Control -> Advanced`

Answer (score 7):

You can try following steps

1 Unbind the project in  "Change Source Control" dialog

2 Refresh project to update source control status

3 Right click the project and click Add the Project to source Control in solution explorer

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same issue but the solution is slightly different than those mentioned so far. My project's contents were checked in but the project itself was not. The project's bindings were valid.

In the Team explorer's Source Code Explorer, the project files were greyed out. After a get-latest, TFS opened the Merge Conflicts screen where I could choose to keep the local copy.

After this, the project was part of TFS.